# Youtube API - Order newsubscriptionvideos by publishdate

Tags: youtube-api, subscription

can someone tell me how to order this feed by date?

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/USERNAME/newsubscriptionvideos?alt=json

This does not work oO
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/USERNAME/newsubscriptionvideos?orderby=published&alt=json

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've figured this out. But it seems to work fine for me. I just added the orderby=published.

And I'm using "users/default/newsubscriptionvideos" instead of actually specifying the username. Maybe that makes a difference.